# TCP/ IP event that start reading process

Tags: c#, events, tcp, event-handling, tcpclient

I'm developing a solution to send data from a microcontroller with a GPRS modem ( server) to my application in the computer ( the one client) over a TCP/IP connection.

I designed first my application working with a serial port connection (to go step-by-step that was easier) and now I have to adapt it in order to receive from a socket instead of serial port, which I'm totally new in and I thought it would be more straight.

I've been reading for days and I didn't get anything clear. Most of the solutions I see work just to send and receive a single packet, or are too complicated.

My server is going to be sending packets every second and the client has to read them and then analyze them.

I want something like this:

`this.serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.routineRx);`

But for NetworkStream. Something that wakes up the reading process ( RoutineRx) when there's something to read.

Maybe I have to change my mind and forgetting about this kind of stuff. I'm trying to make the most of my old code.

Maybe I'm asking something that has been asked many times before, but I really didn't find it. If so,sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DataReceived` event for a `NetworkStream`. You can use the `DataAvailable` property to determine when there is data read for you to read, and use `Read` to read that data.

There are indeed many examples of reading/writing TCP data in c#. It's different from reading serial port data, and you may have to rethink your design somewhat.